# Domain Probability function

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory

I am reading the Cassela Berger [book](https://mybiostats.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/casella-berger.pdf) on Statistical Inference. On the page 12 there is the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1.2.11** If $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability function, then
>
> (a) $\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A \cap C_i)$ for any partition $C_1, C_2, \ldots$;

My question about the proof is.. how do we ensure that $A\cap C_i$ belongs to the domain of the function $\mathbb{P}$? The domain is a sigma-algebra.

Comment: There is likely an omitted assumption that the $C_i$ also belong to the sigma algebra.

Comment: Suppose $C_i \in \Sigma$, the $\sigma$-algebra. Alternatively, suppose $A \cap C_i$ does belong to the domain of $\mathbb{P}$, for whatever reason. The crux of the theorem is truly understanding why this relation holds.

Comment: Maybe partition is defined in such a way that $C_k$ belongs to $\sigma-$algebra on $\Omega$?